# how to create table in mysql with the contents of first row in excel in java dynamicallly

Tags: java, mysql, excel, spring, maven

How to create table in MySQL with the  contents of first row in excel in java dynamically without hard-coding and creating and I have a excel in which columns are added or deleted frequently... so I need to update my table frequently with new columns.. anyone please help. I am using spring-jdbc to connect to database and creating maven project... and how to read a cell value with date in it with format MM/DD/YYYY? for reading excel data I am using Apache-poi..

I want table in mysql like

```
ID  Employee Manager   Onsite  4/15/2015    4/16/2015  4/17/2015
```

How do I create? Please refer the below excel..the major thing is after two day again another date column will be added to my excel..that also I need to save in table previously that I have created..I am not getting idea how it can be done... I can't create the table as I have created in my code...

My excel is like this.. and having more than 100 rows

```
ID        Employee    Manager    Onsite        4/15/2015   4/16/2015  4/17/2015
1           raju        ram      offshore        8            8          8
```

My code

```
package controller;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import model.PMOEmployee;





import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;






    public class ExcelDBJDBCDAO implements ExcelDBDAO {

        private DataSource dataSource;

        private  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            return dataSource;
        }

        public void setdataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
        }

        public JdbcTemplate getjdbcTemplate() {
            return jdbcTemplate;
        }

        public void setjdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }

        public void importdata() {
             TODO Auto-generated method stub
             table creation
            String sql="create table PMO(Id int ,Employee varchar(50),Manager varchar(50),Onsite varchar(50))";
            getjdbcTemplate().update(sql);        
    System.out.println("table created Successfully :)");


            ArrayList<PMOEmployee> list = new ArrayList<PMOEmployee>();

            try
            {
                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/svenkatakishore/Untitled 1.xls"));

                //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

                //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                //Iterate through each rows one by one
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                while (rowIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                    PMOEmployee employee = new PMOEmployee();
                    //For each row, iterate through all the columns

                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();                 
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                    {

                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                        switch (cell.getCellType())
                        {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0) {
                                employee.setId((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } 

                            break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
                                    employee.setEmployeeName(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                }
                                else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 2) {
                                    employee.setManager(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                }
                                else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 3) {
                                    employee.setOnsite(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                }


                                break;


                        }
                    }
                    String sql1 = "INSERT INTO PMO(Id,Employee,Manager,Onsite) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    getjdbcTemplate().update(sql1, new Object[]{employee.getId(),employee.getEmployeeName(),
                            employee.getManager(),employee.getOnsite()});

                }
                file.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    

            }



        }
```

myoutput

```
 ID     Employee       Manager   Onsite  
 1      raju           ram       offsore
```

Comment: Post your POI code that is reading XL file. Read date cell as a date only

Comment: your column labels are date values?

Comment: hi ravinder i have added my code.. how to read date cell as date? is there anything like Cell.CELL_TYPE_DATE? i didnt get u yar.

Comment: hi ravinder.. how can i use the 1st row contents of excel to create a table with them in mysql... @Ravinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because the spreadsheet returns the date cell value as integer. You need to check if your cell contains date, and work accordingly. This can be done by using DateUtil class. For e.g.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.ge`enter code here`tSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext())
            {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                switch (cell.getCellType())
                {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue() + "\t\t\t\t");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t\t");
                }
                break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t\t");
                        break;
//                       case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
//                           System.out.println("0"+ "\t\t");
//                           break;

                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    

    }
```

Comment: hi Aakash...I need to create table using the contents of 1st row in excel..can u plz help. the date column is frequently added to my excel..so can u suggest anything.

Comment: @KishoreVenkat, do you have any specific question? Please post and give something that you have **developed**. We will try to  Please ask some specific questions, and we will try to answer. But if you think that we will develop a program for you, sorry. That can't be done. You have to work yourself.

Comment: @KishoreVenkat and by the way, have you checked and tested my answer to your question? If not, then please check. If yes and if it solved your problem of getting cell value as date, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: hi i am sorry i new to stackoverflow..ya i have updated my work...kindly have a look Aakash...if anything else required plz comment yar..

Comment: You should change your logic to something below 

`if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0) {
                                employee.setId((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            } 
if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 4) {
                                employee.setXXX((int)cell.getDateCellValue());
                            } 
if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 5) {
                                employee.setXXX((int)cell.getDateCellValue());
                            }`

Comment: ya ok Aakash..but what if a new column has been added to my excel..how do i change then? how do i update my table yar..i am stuck there Aakash....

Comment: In that case, instead of using `PMOEmployee` object, you should create a `java.util.List` object, add all the cell's value in that list, and use that list to create your SQL statement. Moreover, don't use cell index to identify the content. Simply put cell's value in your list. Since you cannot control the format and sequence of your excel, you will have to do this. It has a risk of putting your values in in-correct columns, if format of excel changes.